# How to translate this curl call into Go?

Tags: go, curl

I have the following curl call:

```
curl \
--request POST \
--header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
--header "Authorization: Basic XXXX" \
--data-urlencode 'A=B' \
--data-urlencode 'C=D' \
"https://www.myexample.com/mypath?param1=foobar"
```

How can I write Go code that will do the exact same thing?

So far, I have successfully constructed the full URL and am sending it to `http.NewRequestWithContext()`

```
u, err := url.Parse("https://www.myexample.com" + "/mypath")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
q := u.Query()
u.RawQuery = q.Encode()


http.NewRequestWithContext(myContext, http.MethodPost, u.String(), nil)
response, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(myContext, http.MethodPost, s.cfg.BaseDRAPI + oAuthPath, nil)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

However, I do not know where/how to specify the headers and the two data fields.
Please help!

Comment: `http.NewRequestWithContext` returns the request, not the response. You can add the headers to that request before you send it with the `http.Client.Do` method.

Comment: https://mholt.github.io/curl-to-go/ is a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Create the request and send it as below. Handle the error and response according to your application.

```
    endpoint := "https://www.myexample.com/mypath?param1=foobar"
    data := url.Values{}
    data.Set("A", "B")
    data.Set("C", "D")

    //create new POST request to the url and encoded form Data
    r, err := http.NewRequest("POST", endpoint, strings.NewReader(data.Encode())) // URL-encoded payload
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //set headers to the request
    r.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")  //this is a must for form data encoded request
    r.Header.Add("Authorization", "Basic XXXX")

    //send request and get the response
    client := &http.Client{}
    res, err := client.Do(r)
    if err != nil {
        //handle error
        log.Fatal(`error: `,err)
    }
    log.Println(res.Status)
    //handle response part here
```