# How to add Parameters, Data, and Headers to a POST request in Golang?

Tags: http, go, networking, request, http-headers

Is there any way to add headers and data to an HTTP request in Golang, as well as URL parameters? I have tried to add data to a POST request, but it seems Golang just isn't meant for sending any kind of complex request. After much research online I'm not sure if there's a way, but if anyone knows how, please tell me!

Comment: Yes you can do those things.  It's a bit hard to help without your code buty I assume you are using a `http.Request`.  So eg to add a header use `request.Header().Add()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to translate this curl call into Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68684593/how-to-translate-this-curl-call-into-go)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. See [How to set headers in http get request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864302/how-to-set-headers-in-http-get-request), it answers your question. Also, you can find more information about the default http package in https://pkg.go.dev/net/http.